# Zune crashes after startup

Tags: windows, ms-security-essentials, zune

When I launch Zune software, it works fine for a few seconds and then crashes with a "Zune has encountered a problem and needs to close" error. How can I fix it?

I am running a Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate with Microsoft Security Essentials antivirus software.

Comment: What version of the Zune software are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you must reinstall the [software](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929358) OR try [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071225100217AAumCXT). Hope it helps you.